# How to get Up Event in SearchView android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-search

I need to implement some action after clicking the up icon after searching in my **`ListView`** via **`SearchView`**. How can i get **`UP`** event, i.e. how can i implement the click event for **`UP`** icon.

[image: Up icon encircled in Red.]

Comment: i think what your looking for is `android.R.id.home` , more from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp)

Comment: Nope,I have tried using `android.R.id.home` which didn't work coz this one is associated to `SearchView` widget not to go back to parent or home activity.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer, Instead of relying on **`UP`** icon event, i implemented **`OnActionExpandListener`** which worked exactly what i wanted.

```
menuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item)
            {
                // Do something when collapsed

                return true; // Return true to collapse action view
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item)
            {
                // Do something when Expanded
                return true;
            }
        });
```